# Yii2: slug not working

Tags: yii2, slug, yii-url-manager

My `PageController` looks like:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\Page;
use yii\base\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class PageController extends Controller
{

  public  function actionIndex($slug){
         var_dump($slug);exit;
  }
}
```

And my `urlManager` looks like this:

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'page/<slug>' => 'page/index',
        ]
    ],
```

When I hit a URL as `http://localhost/myproject/page/about-us` I get error:

> Too few arguments to function
>   app\controllers\PageController::actionIndex(),  0 passed and exactly 1
>   expected.

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you see what route it's trying to parse in deubg?

Comment: not exactly, look for "Route requested" and "Route to run"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
use yii\base\Controller;
```

use

```
use yii\web\Controller;
```